# Looking for sentiment model for twitter using Stanford NLP

Tags: twitter, model, nlp, stanford-nlp

Is there any sentiment model for twitter ?  I am using Stanford NLP for sentiment analysis, but it always give negative result if there are any ungrammatical issue on sentence. It might caused by the default trained model which is based on movie reviews. So I need a well trained sentiment model for unstructured or ungrammatical sentence like those in twitter, to which I can set the "sentiment.model'like this:

```
 Properties props = new Properties();
 props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, parse,sentiment");       
 props.put("sentiment.model", "sentiment.ser.gz");       
 pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own model and retrain it: 
http://nlp.stanford.edu/sentiment/code.html

Comment: yes, but I am not native speaker, that is why I am looking for a well done model here :)